# Computer name changes and interferes with handling of file locks in Emacs

Tags: macos, emacs

Emacs handles file locks by creating a symbolic link, for example:

```
> ls -la
lrwxr-xr-x    1 miguel  staff     25 Jul 20 18:21 .#test.md -> miguel@MiguelsMBP1004.548
```

In another folder with a file modified earlier, the computer name was different:

```
> ls -la
lrwxr-xr-x   1 miguel  staff      41 Jul 20 17:53 .#gtd.org -> miguel@Miguels-MacBook-Pro-1004.local.548
```

When I ask to save this latter file, Emacs says `... locked by miguel@Miguel... (pid548): (s, q, p, ?)?`.

The computer name with `system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType` is none of these two, but `Computer Name: Miguel’s MacBook Pro (3)`.

Sometimes, the computer name reverts back to the first and Emacs "owns the lock" again. I would rather avoid disabling the locking feature with setting `create-lock-files` to `nil`.

This happens in both El Capitan 10.11.6 and High Sierra 10.13.4.

How can I set the computer name that Emacs uses to a constant value?

**Update (24 July 2018)**: I changed the computer name to `colossus` in El Capitan and still have the same problem where Emacs sometimes uses `colossus` and sometimes `colossus.local`. In High Sierra, I changed the computer name too, but Emacs uses another computer name, `user@laptop-1234.company.domain`. How can I set the computer name that Emacs uses in interlocking?

Comment: [Same question](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5sxejq/foo_locked_by_stefandefiant_pid_1234_s_q_p_what/) on reddit, but no answer to locking warning when network roaming.

Comment: Thanks for the flag. I read it and am trying a few things to see if any of them work.